# How do I get SourceTree my credentials for a custom Mercurial endpoint?

Tags: mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

I've been trying to get SourceTree to communicate with my company's Mercurial remote repository but I seem to be failing. On the command line, I can get `hg pull` working just fine (it authenticates with my id_rsa private key without any trouble), but when I try to pull through the UI, it just spins. I have an embedded Mercurial install as well as a separate hg install on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue, as it turns out, has to do with the SSH client configuration in the settings. While Git can use any SSH keys available, Mercurial requires the SSH key to be in `ppk` format. The good news is that this is available through Tools > Create or Import SSH Keys. This will launch PuTTY Key Generator.

1. Click "Load" and then set the dropdown for file types to "*.*".
2. Navigate to the location of the private key file and load `id_rsa` or similar.
3. Click "Save private key". This will output the ppk file.
4. Go back to SourceTree and choose Tools > Options
5. Set the SSH client to Putty/Plink.
6. Browse for the ppk file you just created.

Comment: 1. Mercurial|SourceTree does **not require** ppk-keys, in depends from configured in settings ssh-client (and relevant), which can be plink (+pagent for keys) or classic ssh with OpenSSH keys for both HG or ST (see in Tools > Options > General > SSH Client Configuration for SourceTree setup)

Comment: @LazyBadger The text next to the SSH Client says, "(Git only, Mercurial always uses Plink on Windows)". I tried passing the unmodified private key and had no luck. Switching to PPK made it work.